# MySQL MAX Function mixes rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the query `SELECT id, MAX(value) FROM table1` and it returns the correct value, but it takes the first id of the table instead of the one corresponding to the value returned (id is primary key).
I've already seen solutions, but they all needed a WHERE clause which i can't use in my case.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3399890)

Comment: Think about it, any `id` you output from that query will make no sense. You are agregating a number of rows so any one of the id's from any of the rows being used has no meaning

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to do is return the id of the row with the max value.  Is that right?

I'm curious why you can't use a WHERE clause?

But ok, using that constraint this can be solved.  I'm going to assume that your table is unique on id (if not, you should really talk to whoever built it and ask *why* ?)

```
SELECT id, value 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This will sort your table, by value descending (greatest -> least), and then only show the first row (ie, the row with the largest "value").

If your table is *not* unique on id, you can still group by ID and get the same

```
SELECT id, max(value) as max_value
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY max_value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Seems better than my solution, great.

Comment: These are  non deterministic ("random") sorts where **any** matching record where `value` column values are equal could be the *"first"* match, besides that the record result can change on every request... Anyhow there is no thing as first in SQL, without defining a deterministic (fixed) sort to define how to handle ties which pagination / batching **always** requires meaning using `ORDER BY value DESC, id ASC/DESC` asuming id column having a `PRIMARY/UNIQUE` key..

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer why your query is behaving in the way you observe: I suspect you are running without `sql_mode = only_full_group_by` as your query would likely [generate an error otherwise](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).  As you've noticed, this can lead to somewhat odd results.

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want.

In this case, since you have no `GROUP BY` clause, the entire table is effectively the group.

---

To get one id associated with the largest value in the table, you can select all the rows, order by the value (descending), and then just limit to the first result, no need for the aggregation operator (or a `WHERE` caluse):

```sql
SELECT id, value FROM table1 ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1
```

Note that if there are multiple ids with the (same) max value, this only returns one of them.  In the comments, @RaymondNijland points out that this may give different results (for `id`, the `value` will always be the maximum) each time you run it, and you can make it more deterministic by ordering by `id` as well:

```sql
SELECT id, value FROM table1 ORDER BY value DESC, id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Likewise, if there are for some reason multiple values for the same ID, it will still return that ID if one of its rows happens to be the max value -- thankfully this doesn't apply in this case, as you mentioned that `id` is the primary key.

Comment: You appear to have completely removed the `MAX()` function, was that intensional

Comment: Its true, I have, because it isn't necessary.  Ordering by value in a descending order will have the first result be a row with the max value.

Comment: ... no ... @robsiemb this is where you are wrong.. This is a non deterministic ("random") sort where **any** matching record where `value` column values are equal could be the *"first"*, besides that the record result can change on every request..

Comment: As I noted, it will give you _a_ row with the max value, but the question isn't clear if it is looking for a single row or all rows.

Comment: anyhow then i misread a bit what you meant anyhow there is no thing as first in SQL, without defining a deterministic (fixed) sort to define how to handle ties which pagination / batching **always** requires meaning using `ORDER BY value DESC, id ASC/DESC` asuming id column having a `PRIMARY/UNIQUE` key..

Comment: Thanks, I've incorporated your clarification, its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a group by clause :

```
SELECT id, MAX(value) FROM table1 GROUP BY id
```

EDIT : To answer your need you could do

```
SELECT id, MAX(value) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(value) = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table1)
```

This could give you multiple results if you have multiple ids with the max value. In this case you could add "LIMIT 1" to get only one result but that would be quite strange and random.

Comment: that returns more results than i want it to (it returns two ids even though it should only return the actual max value id)

Comment: See my edit (I did not use where clause as you told you couldn't use one for whatever reason)